# Do Not touch TFS database directly

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have seen in many blog posts that we should not query directly to TFS databases else it will void the support agreement or it is not supported.

If anyone can guide me to the proper documentation from microsoft please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, I am not a lawyer so *caveat emptor*.

From the [License Directory](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/) you will read in the [TFS 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mt171584/)  license terms that the *SCOPE OF LICENSE* section forbids:

> reverse engineer, decompile or disassemble the software, or attempt to do so, except and only to the extent required by third party licensing terms governing the use of certain open-source components that may be included with the software;

As database schema is not documented, you have your answer.

Comment: Just because it is not written there, doesn't mean it is allowed. Unfortunately I couldn't find a statement directly for TFS, but I found an older one for SharePoint, which is like general rule from Microsoft:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-products-and-by-windows-sharepoint-services